# How to convert image A to image B having pixel rules in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch, gpu

So I have 2 a WxH single-channel images X and Y as my network results. I have another single-channel image P of size WxH. I want to process P so that:

```
P'(x,y) ← P( x + scale * (X(x,y) - 0.5), y + scale * (Y(x,y) - 0.5))
```

where P(x,y) is the input image, in, and P'(x,y) is the destination. X(x,y) and Y(x,y) are the values of the images my network returned to me. I want to do it with PyTorch so that it can be done on GPU and integrated into my training pipeline. How to do such operations on image P to get P' in PyTorch?

Comment: `x + scale * (X(x,y) - 0.5)` and `y + scale * (Y(x,y) - 0.5)` are not a priori whole, how do you handle that?

Comment: Check `torch.nn.functional.grid_sample`